# Checar o deschecar un CheckBox dependiendo de una variable

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Requiero mostrar un checkBox bien sea marcado o desmarcado segun el valor Boolean de una variable.
si el valor de mi variable es true el checBox se mostraria Marcado, entonces, si es false se me mostraria desmarcado.

tengo estos dos checkBox:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="lunes" id="lunes"   checked="false"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="martes" id="martes" checked="true"></td>
```

la idea seria que el Checked sea comparado con una variable

lo he intendado de esa forma y tambien de la siguiente, desde el Js

```
document.getElementById("lunes").checked = true;
document.getElementById("martes").checked = false;
```

tampoco me funciono

Comment: Tu código funciona amigo, no se como lo este utilizando pero si funciona. Al cargar el html sale checked lunes y martes no.

Comment: Si sale, pero se me muestran marcados sin importar si igualo a true o false

Comment: Es que soy muy nuevo usando estas Tecnologias, puede que este preguntando tonteras, pero segun lo que entiendo al igualar el checked = false, se deberia mostrar el checkBox desmarcado, al contrario, si igualo el Checked = true, se deberia mostrar el CheckBox  marcado. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Answer (score 0):

No hay valores que hagan que la casilla de verificación se desmarque. Si el atributo **checked** existe, la casilla de verificación se marcará independientemente del valor que se haya establecido.

Para que una casilla no este **Marcada** entonces lo único que tienes que hacer es no ponerle el atributo **checked**.

```html
<td><input type="checkbox" name="lunes" id="lunes" checked></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="martes" id="martes"></td>
```

Si no existe el parámetro entonces no aparecerá marcado. Cualquier valor dentro de las comillas de **checked** dará como resultado un **true**.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox" checked="" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="unchecked" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="true" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="false" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="on" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="off" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="1" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="0" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="yes" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="no" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="y" />
<input type="checkbox" checked="n" />
```

Referencia: [mpen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613192/7011427)

Si por ejemplo tienes una variable que es **true** utilizas tu segundo fragmento de código:

```js
let mivar = true;
//aqui si puede ser true o false
document.getElementById("lunes").checked = mivar;
document.getElementById("martes").checked = mivar;
```

```html
<td><input type="checkbox" name="lunes" id="lunes" checked></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="martes" id="martes"></td>
```

Comment: Como haria entonces si quiero poner a funcionar que se marque o desmarque desde el inicio segun el valor de una variable que puede ser true o False

Comment: @LeLo ya te lo agregue en la respuesta, la edite.

Comment: Gracias....

Aun no me funciona, pero puede ser que tenga algo mas mal, porque por todo lado que busco me indican esto mismo.

Saludos.